# Produce three ts lines into two stacked graphs of plots with a shared x-axis

Tags: r, plot

I'm revising my question to base it upon an reproducible example:

I have three quarterly time series variables for 2020Q1-2021Q4 as follows:

```
A <- ts(c(1,2,3,4,2,3,6,3), start=c(2020,1), end=c(2021,4), frequency = 4)
B <- ts(c(2,3,6,3,4,5,2,1), start=c(2020,1), end=c(2021,4), frequency = 4)
C <- ts(c(4,5,2,1,3,2,5,3), start=c(2020,1), end=c(2021,4), frequency = 4)
```

As I would like to plot A and B into one graph, I combined them and plotted as follows:

```
AB.ts <- cbind(A, B)
pdf("AB.pdf",height=5)
ts.plot(AB.ts, col=1:2, lty=1:2, xlim=c(2020, 2021), ylim=c(0, 7), xlab = "")
dev.off()
```

which produced:

[image]

And I plotted C separately:

```
C.ts <- C
pdf("C.pdf",height=5)
ts.plot(C.ts, xlim=c(2020, 2021), ylim=c(0, 7), xlab = "")
dev.off()
```

which produced:

[image]

The x-axis of both graphs looks strange. Why doesn't it show the time range of 2020Q1 to 2020Q4?

Anyway, now I would like to stack the two graphs with a shared x-axis. It should look something like this which I manually produced:

[image]

The space between the two graphs is unnecessary.

I tried to produce a code myself but failed. I would like to get help produce a right code.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). We do not have access to your .csv files.

Comment: @Parfait, following your advice, I rewrote my question totally to base it upon a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider staying with base R graphics, using various `par` settings:

**Data** *(randomized data)*

```r
set.seed(20240112)
roes.ts <- ts(runif(435, min=-10, max=20), start = c(1984, 1), end = c(2020, 3), frequency = 4)
dsr.ts <- ts(runif(435, min=5, max=15), start = c(1984, 1), end = c(2020, 3), frequency = 4)
```

**Plot**

```r
par(mfrow=c(2, 1))                     # SET PLOT REGION OF TWO ROWS BY ONE COLUMN
par(mar=c(0,3,2,0), xaxt="n", las=1)   # HIDE X-AXIS WITH ZERO BOTTOM MARGIN
ts.plot(roes.ts, col=1:2, lty=1:2, xlim=c(1984, 2020), ylim=c(-10, 20), ylab="roes.ts", xlab = "")
par(mar=c(2,3,0,0), xaxt="s", las=1)   # SHOW X-AXIS WITH NON-ZERO BOTTOM MARGIN
ts.plot(dsr.ts, col=1:2, lty=1:2, xlim=c(1984, 2020), ylim=c(5, 15), ylab="dsr.ts", xlab = "")
```

[image: Plot Output]

Comment: Thank you! Your plots look a little different from what I'm looking for. I have added Edit to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: Since I don't have your data, I used randomized numeric vectors. Simply replace the `runif` calls with your time series, `roes` and `dsr`, pulled from your CSV data and lines may reproduce. See my comment above with link on how to set up an R reprex for sample of your data.

Comment: Following your advice, I rewrote my question totally to base it upon a reproducible example.

Comment: Great! Nevertheless, I hope you were able to integrate your actual data with this graphing solution using `par` + `ts.plot`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not sure what is to be done with `par`+`ts.plot`.

Comment: In any case, your solution suggested here worked! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

`cbind` and `plot` it.

```
cbind(roes.ts, dsr.ts) |> plot(main='My title')
```

[image]

This works because

```
> class(cbind(roes.ts, dsr.ts))
[1] "mts"    "ts"     "matrix" "array"
```

and dispatches `stats:::plot.ts()`.

Or using `lattice::xyplot`

```
> lattice::xyplot(cbind(roes.ts, dsr.ts))
```

[image]

We could also `list` the `"ts"` objects and employ `mapply`.

```
ts_lst <- list(roes.ts=roes.ts, dsr.ts=dsr.ts)
op <- par(mfrow=c(2, 1), mar=c(0, 4, 0, 0), oma=c(3, 2, 2, 2), las=1)
mapply(plot, ts_lst, ylim=list(range(roes.ts), range(dsr.ts)),
       ylab=names(ts_lst), xaxt=c('n', 's'), type='l',
       MoreArgs=list(col=1:2, lty=1:2, xlim=c(1984, 2020), xlab=''))
par(op)
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

borrowed from *Parfait*'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77810432/6574038).

Comment: Thank, jay.sf! Your plots look a little different from what I'm looking for. I have added Edit to clarify what I'm looking for.

Comment: @ppp Your question lacks of reproducibility. *Parfait* has added an important [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77809704/produce-three-ts-lines-into-two-stacked-graphs-of-plots-with-a-shared-x-axis/77810712?noredirect=1#comment137173960_77809704) to your question, that you might want to consider.

Comment: Following your advice, I rewrote my question totally to base it upon a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your two datasets into one, before turning it into a `ts` object.
The `ggfortify` package provides support for `ts` objects within `ggplot2`.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggfortify)

# Create data that is similiar to what yours should look like.
roes <- data.frame(roes1 = runif(36,-5, 15),
                   roes2 = runif(36, 6, 16))
head(roes)
#>       roes1     roes2
#> 1 11.610142 10.257512
#> 2  5.888285 14.721635
#> 3  7.618143  6.899824
#> 4  4.558857 12.344110
#> 5 13.606782 11.517959
#> 6  6.163015 10.885487

dsr <- data.frame(dsr1 = runif(36, 9, 13))
head(dsr)
#>        dsr1
#> 1 12.353777
#> 2  9.899284
#> 3 12.798054
#> 4 11.097071
#> 5 12.955612
#> 6  9.863011

# Bind data by the columns and turn in to ts object.
roes_dsr <-
  bind_cols(roes, dsr) |>
  ts(
    start = c(1984, 1),
    end = c(2020, 3),
    frequency = 4
  )
```

`autoplot()` creates a facetted line plot.

```r
autoplot(roes_dsr)
```

[image]

You can theme the plot to your liking.

```r
autoplot(roes_dsr) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA)
  )
```

[image]

To get the exact plot you specified, we need to `pivot_longer()` the data
and write the `ggplot` code
manually. Luckily `ggfortify:::get.dtindex(roes_dsr)` helps to extract
the time information from the `ts` object.

```r
roes_dsr |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  mutate(time = ggfortify:::get.dtindex(roes_dsr)) |> 
  pivot_longer(-time) |> 
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(time, value)) +
  facet_wrap(
    vars(name),
    ncol = 1,
    scales = "free_y",
    strip.position = "left"
  ) +
  ylab("") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.placement = "outside",
    panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"),
    panel.border = element_rect(color = "black", fill = NA)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Instead of three separate plots, I would like to have two plots combined into one graph, like the first graph in my post, and have the third plot separately. Eventually, I would have two stacked graphs. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: I rewrote my question totally to base it upon a reproducible example.